# Jetty 10 redirect http to https

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-10

I am trying to modify Jetty 10.0.15 to handle http to https redirection. I tried searching in their official Operations guide but i cant find anything. For example:

http://localhost:8443/login?lang=en -> https://localhost:8443/login?lang=en

or also have the option to redirect http 8081 port to https post 8443

http://localhost:8081/login?lang=en -> https://localhost:8443/login?lang=en

Is this possible? Do i need to modify the ssl.ini or http.ini files in the start.d folder? In my webapps folder i am also using a context file xml.

Thanks!

PS here are the ini files:

ssl.ini

```
# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: ssl
# Enables a TLS (SSL) connector to support secure protocols.
# Secure HTTP/1.1 is provided by enabling the "https" module and secure HTTP/2 is provided by enabling the "http2" module.
# --------------------------------------- 
--module=ssl

### TLS (SSL) Connector Configuration

## The host/address to bind the connector to.
# jetty.ssl.host=0.0.0.0

## The port the connector listens on.
jetty.ssl.port=8443

## The connector idle timeout, in milliseconds.
# jetty.ssl.idleTimeout=30000

## The number of acceptors (-1 picks a default value based on number of cores).
# jetty.ssl.acceptors=1

## The number of selectors (-1 picks a default value based on number of cores).
# jetty.ssl.selectors=-1

## The ServerSocketChannel accept queue backlog (0 picks the platform default).
# jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize=0

## The thread priority delta to give to acceptor threads.
# jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta=0

## Whether to enable the SO_REUSEADDR socket option.
# jetty.ssl.reuseAddress=true

## Whether to enable the SO_REUSEPORT socket option.
# jetty.ssl.reusePort=false

## Whether to enable the TCP_NODELAY socket option on accepted sockets.
# jetty.ssl.acceptedTcpNoDelay=true

## The SO_RCVBUF socket option to set on accepted sockets.
## A value of -1 indicates that the platform default is used.
# jetty.ssl.acceptedReceiveBufferSize=-1

## The SO_SNDBUF socket option to set on accepted sockets.
## A value of -1 indicates that the platform default is used.
# jetty.ssl.acceptedSendBufferSize=-1

## Whether client SNI data is required for all secure connections.
## When SNI is required, clients that do not send SNI data are rejected with an HTTP 400 response.
# jetty.ssl.sniRequired=false

## Whether client SNI data is checked to match CN and SAN in server certificates.
## When SNI is checked, if the match fails the connection is rejected with an HTTP 400 response.
# jetty.ssl.sniHostCheck=true

## The max age, in seconds, for the Strict-Transport-Security response header.
# jetty.ssl.stsMaxAgeSeconds=31536000

## Whether to include the subdomain property in any Strict-Transport-Security header.
# jetty.ssl.stsIncludeSubdomains=true

### SslContextFactory Configuration
## Note that OBF passwords are not secure, just protected from casual observation.

## Whether client SNI data is required for all secure connections.
## When SNI is required, clients that do not send SNI data are rejected with a TLS handshake error.
# jetty.sslContext.sniRequired=false

## The Endpoint Identification Algorithm.
## Same as javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters#setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(String).
# jetty.sslContext.endpointIdentificationAlgorithm=

## The JSSE Provider.
# jetty.sslContext.provider=

## The KeyStore file path (relative to $JETTY_BASE).
# jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath=etc/keystore.p12
## The KeyStore absolute file path.
# jetty.sslContext.keyStoreAbsolutePath=${jetty.base}/etc/keystore.p12

## The TrustStore file path (relative to $JETTY_BASE).
# jetty.sslContext.trustStorePath=etc/keystore.p12
## The TrustStore absolute file path.
# jetty.sslContext.trustStoreAbsolutePath=${jetty.base}/etc/keystore.p12

## The KeyStore password.
# jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword=

## The Keystore type.
# jetty.sslContext.keyStoreType=PKCS12

## The KeyStore provider.
# jetty.sslContext.keyStoreProvider=

## The KeyManager password.
# jetty.sslContext.keyManagerPassword=

## The TrustStore password.
# jetty.sslContext.trustStorePassword=

## The TrustStore type.
# jetty.sslContext.trustStoreType=PKCS12

## The TrustStore provider.
# jetty.sslContext.trustStoreProvider=

## Whether client certificate authentication is required.
# jetty.sslContext.needClientAuth=false

## Whether client certificate authentication is desired, but not required.
# jetty.sslContext.wantClientAuth=false

## Whether cipher order is significant.
# jetty.sslContext.useCipherSuitesOrder=true

## The SSLSession cache size.
# jetty.sslContext.sslSessionCacheSize=-1

## The SSLSession cache timeout (in seconds).
# jetty.sslContext.sslSessionTimeout=-1

## Whether TLS renegotiation is allowed.
# jetty.sslContext.renegotiationAllowed=true

## The max number of TLS renegotiations per connection.
# jetty.sslContext.renegotiationLimit=5
```

server.ini

```
# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: server
# Enables and configures the Jetty server.
# This module does not enable any network protocol support.
# To enable a specific network protocol such as HTTP/1.1, you must enable the correspondent Jetty module.
# --------------------------------------- 
--module=server

### Common HTTP configuration
## Scheme to use to build URIs for secure redirects
#jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme=https

## Port to use to build URIs for secure redirects
jetty.httpConfig.securePort=8443

## Response content buffer size (in bytes)
# jetty.httpConfig.outputBufferSize=32768

## Max response content write length that is buffered (in bytes)
# jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize=8192

## Max request headers size (in bytes)
# jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize=8192

## Max response headers size (in bytes)
# jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize=8192

## Whether to send the Server: header
# jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion=true

## Whether to send the Date: header
# jetty.httpConfig.sendDateHeader=false

## Max per-connection header cache size (in nodes)
# jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize=1024

## Whether, for requests with content, delay dispatch until some content has arrived
# jetty.httpConfig.delayDispatchUntilContent=true

## Maximum number of error dispatches to prevent looping
# jetty.httpConfig.maxErrorDispatches=10

## Relative Redirect Locations allowed
# jetty.httpConfig.relativeRedirectAllowed=false

## Whether to use direct ByteBuffers for reading or writing
# jetty.httpConfig.useInputDirectByteBuffers=true
# jetty.httpConfig.useOutputDirectByteBuffers=true

## HTTP Compliance: RFC7230, RFC7230_LEGACY, RFC2616, RFC2616_LEGACY, LEGACY
# jetty.httpConfig.compliance=RFC7230

## URI Compliance: DEFAULT, LEGACY, RFC3986, RFC3986_UNAMBIGUOUS, UNSAFE
# jetty.httpConfig.uriCompliance=DEFAULT

## Cookie compliance mode for parsing request Cookie headers: RFC6265_STRICT, RFC6265, RFC6265_LEGACY, RFC2965, RFC2965_LEGACY
# jetty.httpConfig.requestCookieCompliance=RFC6265

## Cookie compliance mode for generating response Set-Cookie: RFC2965, RFC6265
# jetty.httpConfig.responseCookieCompliance=RFC6265

## multipart/form-data compliance mode of: LEGACY(slow), RFC7578(fast)
# jetty.httpConfig.multiPartFormDataCompliance=RFC7578

### Server configuration
## Whether ctrl+c on the console gracefully stops the Jetty server
# jetty.server.stopAtShutdown=true

## Timeout in ms to apply when stopping the server gracefully
# jetty.server.stopTimeout=5000

## Dump the state of the Jetty server, components, and webapps after startup
# jetty.server.dumpAfterStart=false

## Dump the state of the Jetty server, components, and webapps before shutdown
# jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop=false

### Server Scheduler Configuration
## The scheduler thread name, defaults to "Scheduler-{hashCode()}" if blank.
# jetty.scheduler.name=

## Whether the server scheduler threads are daemon.
# jetty.scheduler.daemon=false

## The number of server scheduler threads.
# jetty.scheduler.threads=1
```

http.ini

```
# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: http
# Enables a clear-text HTTP connector.
# By default clear-text HTTP/1.1 is enabled, and clear-text HTTP/2 may be added by enabling the "http2c" module.
# --------------------------------------- 
--module=http

### Clear-Text HTTP Connector Configuration

## The host/address to bind the connector to.
# jetty.http.host=0.0.0.0

## The port the connector listens on.
 jetty.http.port=8081

## The connector idle timeout, in milliseconds.
# jetty.http.idleTimeout=30000

## The number of acceptors (-1 picks a default value based on number of cores).
# jetty.http.acceptors=1

## The number of selectors (-1 picks a default value based on number of cores).
# jetty.http.selectors=-1

## The ServerSocketChannel accept queue backlog (0 picks the platform default).
# jetty.http.acceptQueueSize=0

## The thread priority delta to give to acceptor threads.
# jetty.http.acceptorPriorityDelta=0

## Whether to enable the SO_REUSEADDR socket option.
# jetty.http.reuseAddress=true

## Whether to enable the SO_REUSEPORT socket option.
# jetty.http.reusePort=false

## Whether to enable the TCP_NODELAY socket option on accepted sockets.
# jetty.http.acceptedTcpNoDelay=true

## The SO_RCVBUF socket option to set on accepted sockets.
## A value of -1 indicates that the platform default is used.
# jetty.http.acceptedReceiveBufferSize=-1

## The SO_SNDBUF socket option to set on accepted sockets.
## A value of -1 indicates that the platform default is used.
# jetty.http.acceptedSendBufferSize=-1
```

https.ini

```
# --------------------------------------- 
# Module: https
# Adds HTTPS protocol support to the TLS(SSL) Connector.
# --------------------------------------- 
--module=https
```

list-config

```
Enabled Modules:
----------------
  0) bytebufferpool            transitive provider of bytebufferpool for server
                               ini template available with --add-module=bytebufferpool
  1) resources                 transitive provider of resources for logging-jetty
  2) logging/slf4j             transitive provider of logging/slf4j for logging-jetty
                               dynamic dependency of logging-jetty
  3) logging-jetty             transitive provider of logging for threadpool
                               transitive provider of logging for server
                               transitive provider of logging for console-capture
  4) threadpool                transitive provider of threadpool for server
                               ini template available with --add-module=threadpool
  5) server                    ${jetty.base}\start.d\server.ini
  6) jndi                      transitive provider of jndi for plus
  7) security                  transitive provider of security for webapp
                               transitive provider of security for plus
  8) servlet                   transitive provider of servlet for webapp
                               transitive provider of servlet for jsp
  9) webapp                    transitive provider of webapp for plus
                               transitive provider of webapp for deploy
                               ini template available with --add-module=webapp
 10) plus                      transitive provider of plus for annotations
 11) annotations               ${jetty.base}\start.d\annotations.ini
 12) apache-jsp                transitive provider of apache-jsp for jsp
 13) apache-jstl               transitive provider of apache-jstl for jstl
 14) console-capture           ${jetty.base}\start.d\console-capture.ini
 15) deploy                    ${jetty.base}\start.d\deploy.ini
 16) ssl                       ${jetty.base}\start.d\ssl.ini
 17) https                     ${jetty.base}\start.d\https.ini
 18) jsp                       ${jetty.base}\start.d\jsp.ini
 19) jstl                      ${jetty.base}\start.d\jstl.ini
 20) secure-redirect           ${jetty.base}\start.d\secure-redirect.ini
 21) test-keystore             ${jetty.base}\start.d\test-keystore.ini

Java Environment:
-----------------
 java.home = C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7+7
 java.vm.vendor = Eclipse Adoptium
 java.vm.version = 17.0.7+7
 java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
 java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
 java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
 java.runtime.version = 17.0.7+7
 java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\Bojan\AppData\Local\Temp\
 user.dir = C:\qaelum\services\Webserver
 user.language = en
 user.country = US

Jetty Environment:
------------------
 jetty.version = 10.0.15
 jetty.tag.version = jetty-10.0.15
 jetty.build = 68017dbd00236bb7e187330d7585a059610f661d
 jetty.home = C:\qaelum\frameworks\jetty10
 jetty.base = C:\qaelum\services\Webserver

Config Search Order:
--------------------
 <command-line>
 ${jetty.base} -> C:\qaelum\services\Webserver
 ${jetty.home} -> C:\qaelum\frameworks\jetty10

System Properties:
------------------
 (no system properties specified)

Properties:
-----------
 bouncycastle.version = 1.70
 java.version = 17.0.7
 java.version.major = 17
 java.version.micro = 7
 java.version.minor = 0
 java.version.platform = 17
 jetty.base = C:\qaelum\services\Webserver
 jetty.base.uri = file:///C:/qaelum/services/Webserver
 jetty.console-capture.dir = C:\qaelum\services\Webserver\logs
 jetty.home = C:\qaelum\frameworks\jetty10
 jetty.home.uri = file:///C:/qaelum/frameworks/jetty10
 jetty.httpConfig.securePort = 8443
 jetty.ssl.port = 8443
 jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword = OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4
 jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath = etc/test-keystore.p12
 jetty.sslContext.keyStoreType = PKCS12
 jetty.webapp.addServerClasses = org.eclipse.jetty.logging.,${jetty.home.uri}/lib/logging/,org.slf4j.,${jetty.base.uri}/lib/bouncycastle/
 runtime.feature.alpn = true
 slf4j.version = 2.0.5

Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 32 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:                    (dir) | ${jetty.base}\resources
 1:                    2.0.5 | ${jetty.home}\lib\logging\slf4j-api-2.0.5.jar
 2:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\logging\jetty-slf4j-impl-10.0.15.jar
 3:                    4.0.6 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-servlet-api-4.0.6.jar
 4:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-http-10.0.15.jar
 5:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-server-10.0.15.jar
 6:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-xml-10.0.15.jar
 7:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-util-10.0.15.jar
 8:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-io-10.0.15.jar
 9:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-jndi-10.0.15.jar
10:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-security-10.0.15.jar
11:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-servlet-10.0.15.jar
12:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-webapp-10.0.15.jar
13:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-plus-10.0.15.jar
14:                    1.3.3 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar
15:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-annotations-10.0.15.jar
16:                      9.5 | ${jetty.home}\lib\annotations\asm-9.5.jar
17:                      9.5 | ${jetty.home}\lib\annotations\asm-analysis-9.5.jar
18:                      9.5 | ${jetty.home}\lib\annotations\asm-commons-9.5.jar
19:                      9.5 | ${jetty.home}\lib\annotations\asm-tree-9.5.jar
20:                    1.3.5 | ${jetty.home}\lib\annotations\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
21:    3.26.0.v20210609-0549 | ${jetty.home}\lib\apache-jsp\org.eclipse.jdt.ecj-3.26.0.jar
22:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\apache-jsp\org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-10.0.15.jar
23:                   9.0.52 | ${jetty.home}\lib\apache-jsp\org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-9.0.52.jar
24:                   9.0.52 | ${jetty.home}\lib\apache-jsp\org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-9.0.52.jar
25:                    1.2.5 | ${jetty.home}\lib\apache-jstl\org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
26:                    1.2.5 | ${jetty.home}\lib\apache-jstl\org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
27:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-deploy-10.0.15.jar
28:                  10.0.15 | ${jetty.home}\lib\jetty-keystore-10.0.15.jar
29:                1.70.00.0 | ${jetty.base}\lib\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.70.jar
30:                   1.70.0 | ${jetty.base}\lib\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar
31:                1.70.00.0 | ${jetty.base}\lib\bouncycastle\bcutil-jdk15on-1.70.jar

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-bytebufferpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-threadpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-webapp.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\console-capture.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-deploy.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-ssl.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-ssl-context.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-https.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-secure-redirect.xml
 ${jetty.home}\etc\jetty-test-keystore.xml
```

i am also using the test-keystore.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the `secure-redirect` module.

```bash
$ cd /path/to/my-jetty-base
$ java -jar /opt/jetty-home-10.0.15/start.jar --add-module=secure-redirect
```

This will add the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.SecuredRedirectHandler` to your Server.

That will use the information present in the `HttpConfiguration` regarding what ports you consider plain text vs secure to know how to redirect properly (be it 80 to 443, or 8080 to 8443, or even arbitrary ports like 20080 to 20443)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I added the secure-redirect module. My http.ini has port 8081, ssl.ini has 8433 and server.ini securePort=8433. 

The redirect http://localhost:8081/login?lang=en -> https://localhost:8443/login?lang=en = OK 

http://localhost:8443/login?lang=en -> https://localhost:8443/login?lang=en  = NOT WORKING. Am i missing something?

Comment: Your comment is lacking schemes.  Edit your question, and add the contents of your `start.d/ssl.ini`, `start.d/https.ini` and `start.d/http.ini`, along with the results of `java -jar /opt/jetty-home/start.jar --list-config`

Comment: Yes, i added the schemas in the original question